# How to confirm pure-breeding parents

Tags: genetics, population-genetics, gene, epigenetics, quantitative-genetics

I was reading *Genetic Analysis* (Sanders, Bowman) and saw the following figure summarizing the 1909 work of Herman Nilsson-Ehle in describing the genetic control of kernel color in wheat:

[image: Figure 21.1, pg. 711 in 2012 ed.]

How did Nilsson-Ehle determine that the original pure-breeding parents were in fact homozygous for each allele?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. They were probably inbred lines for many generations.

Answer (score 2):

If they are "pure-breeding", that means that they are homozygous.  If they were heterozygous, the offspring would not all have the same color as the parents.  But tree-breeding" means they all do.

Comment: These genes are additive. No dominance relationship is assumed to exist between allele $A_1$ and $A_2$ or between allele $B_1$ and $B_2$.

Answer (score 0):

In Campbell Biology (2021) 12th edition it says that

"True-breeding" (or pure lines) can be verified over *many generations* of self-pollination. If they produce *only* the same variety as the parent plant, then they are homozygous.

Comment: There are more complicated situations, such as if being homozygous at a locus is fatal. You then end up with pure-breeding heterozygotes.