# When doing crosses (Punnett square) with drosophila, how can you be *sure* your parents are *pure lines*?

Tags: genetics, hybridization

In plants, when someone wants to confirm that the parents are pure lines (homozygous) for the alleles studied, the person can self pollinate the plant to make sure that the descendants are identical to the parental plant. (See [How to confirm pure-breeding parents](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/49335/how-to-confirm-pure-breeding-parents))

In drosophila, self-reproduction is not possible so how to *make sure* that the parental strains you are breeding are indeed homozygous for an allele (in an efficient way, I don't want to breed drosophila for 'a lot of successive generations')?

E.g., assuming N is dominant and n recessive, if I have a male (NN) and a female (NN), then the F_1 is all (NN). But, if it happens that I have females that are (Nn) then, all offspring will look like (phenotype) their parents (NN and Nn), but they will have different genotypes. To make sure that the parents are homozygous, should I also verify with the F_2 or the F_1 is good enough? In other words, what is the most efficient way to *verify* that the parents are indeed homozygous?

F2 of F1 (NN) cross from parents (NN) = (NN) (should I be doing a third cross to make sure?)

F2 of F1 (NN and Nn) cross from parents (NN and Nn) = (NN, Nn and nn) => some males (Nn) will mate with females (Nn) giving (NN, Nn and nn) thus confirming that I didn't start with pure lines.

Thus, it really seems to be a long process to *find* the homozygous parents in the first place as you never know *in advance* if you have homozygous parents when you breed them. You have to pick individuals that you *think* are homozygous and test them until *all* the offspring are identical to the parents no matter how long you do it. Is that correct?

Another point here would be to calculate the level of 'confidence' in which we have a pure line. Can we calculate that (and what would be the test to verify that)?

Comment: A very similar question that came up yesterday: https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/104329/59521

Comment: I looked at the answer and it says 'it is always risk that the population is not 100% pure'. My question therefore is how can we calculate our confidence in assuring that we generated a pure line? Basically, how many generations would be needed to be 'convinced' that we have a 'pure line'. Basically, how could I 'confirm' that I indeed have a pure line in an efficient way? Another answer was 'buy it from a supplier' but that is not the type of answer that I expect! I'm curious in knowing whether there is a systematic way for testing a pure line (with relative certainty) What is the standard?

Comment: One is usually acting on the assumption of *random mating*, which implies a sufficiently big population to avoid genetic drift - this includes such rare situations as you described (when all the males are NN, but an substantial part of females are Nn). As for the calculations - I suggest that you ask more specific questions, and show how you tried to do this calculation.

Comment: I added a simple calculation to the linked question. It is not exactly what you ask, but I hope it helps.